# Prevent just one event with javascript

Tags: javascript

My code:

```
var z = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='/redirect']");
for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    z[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    alert('OK');
    });        
}
```

When my script hooks into every /redirect `URLs`. It works but other script prevented too.

Example:

WheI I click /redirect URL

1. Other script -> console.log(1);
2. Other script -> console.log(2);
3. My script -> console.log(3);

It should be:

```
1 2 3
```

But when I use the above script, it prevents all event hooked by others script and the result is:

```
3
```

Can you help my code work better?

Thank you.

Comment: Try adding event listener to the parent if you can and depending upon which was clicked try to do the thing you want to do.